# How does varimax work

Tags: factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I have some questions regarding how varimax works. I read that given an n by k matrix A, the k by k orthogonal matrix B maximises the varimax criterion, which measures the difference of these 2 terms:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j}[AB]_{ij}^4$$

$$(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j}{[AB]_{ij}^2})^2$$

1. The varimax criterion maximises high and low value factor loadings and minimises mid-value factor loadings. How does doing this ensure that the varimax criterion is maximised?
2. In the varimax criterion, the first term is raised to the fourth power while the second term is squared. Why can't the powers of these two terms be 2 and 1 respectively? In other words, why do we have to find the sum of variance of **squared** loadings, rather than simply the sum of variance of loadings?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [*It is said that...*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word).

Answer (score 1):

Varimax seeks to maximize the variance of the squared factor loadings across variables for each factor. It does this by rotating the original factors to a new position. The objective is to make the loadings within a factor either very high or very low, thus making it easier to interpret which variables are strongly associated with which factors.

In the first term, increasing to the fourth power increases the significance of larger loadings, since the effect of re-squaring a number greater than one is amplified. In order to maintain a variance as the objective, the second element is squared, as variance inherently entails squaring. Using powers of 2 and 1 would not adequately amplify the distinction between large and small loadings and might not provide the desired contrast for interpretability.